# keep the selected value for dropdown after submit razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I keep the selected value in the dropdown after the submit button has been used?

```
@{
    var list = new SelectList(new[]
        {
            new {ID="A", Name="All"},
            new {ID="S", Name="Success"},
            new {ID="P", Name="Pending"},
            new {ID="F", Name="Failed"},
        },
        "ID", "Name", 0);
}
@Html.DropDownList("drpStatus", list, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Do you mean getting the value of what is selected in the dropdown, after you submitted your form? If yes, you should bind the value you want to a Model. Have a look at the different ways you can do that here=> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/

Comment: Yes...thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Glad i could help! Can you tell us what it is that helped you so others may benefit from it and maybe i can elaborate more on the topic in a answer.

Comment: Hi Jason,
I have added my code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.
Here is my code.

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpStatus", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["drp_bind"])
```

Controller code:

```
List<SelectListItem> drpStatus = new List<SelectListItem>() {
   new SelectListItem {
       Text = "All", Value = "A" 
   },
   new SelectListItem {
       Text = "Success", Value = "S"
   },
   new SelectListItem {
       Text = "Pending", Value = "P"
   },
   new SelectListItem {
       Text = "Failed", Value = "F"
   },

};
ViewData["drp_bind"] = drpStatus;
```

This is how i bind my dropdown.

Now the main Logic to keep seleted value for dropdown after submit:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Status"] != null)
{
     ViewData["Status"] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Status"]));
     if (ViewData["Status"] != null)

     drpStatus.Where(i => i.Value == ViewData["Status"].ToString()).First().Selected = true;
     ViewData["drp_bind"] = drpStatus;
}
```

`Request.QueryString["Status"] != in this` i am maintaining my selected value in the dropdown ...